# Вывести случайную строку из массива js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой код который генерирует случайное число.

```js
function randomNumber (m,n)
{
  m = parseInt(m);
  n = parseInt(n);
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * (n - m + 1) ) + m;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Начальное значение: <input name="min" type="text" value="1" size="3"><br>
  Конечное значение: <input name="max" type="text" value="30" size="3">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Получить значение" 
      onclick="this.form.num.value=randomNumber(this.form.min.value,this.form.max.value)">
  <input name="num" type="text" id="num" readonly="1">
</form>
```

Как в заданном диапазоне выводить случайное значение из списка

```
list= ["Алексей Анатольевич", "Максим Сергеевич", "Сергей Валерьевич "];
```

С условием что Алексей Анатольевич занимает диапазон от 1-10, Максим Сергеевич от 11-20 и т.д.

Comment: Что вам мешает проверять значение (хотя бы тем же if-else) и возвращать нужное в return?

Comment: Могли бы вы показать как это должно выглядеть? Я начинающий в этом деле и было бы намного проще по примеру разбираться.

Comment: [как-то так](https://jsfiddle.net/L5dwv31r/) тут даже знать ничего особо не надо.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let list= ["Алексей Анатольевич", "Максим Сергеевич", "Сергей Валерьевич "];
function randomNumber (m,n)
{
  m = parseInt(m);
  n = parseInt(n);
  let res =  Math.floor( Math.random() * (n - m + 1) ) + m;
  if(res >= 1 && res <= 10) return list[0];
  else if(res >= 11 && res <= 20) return list[1];
  return list[2];
}
```

```html
<form>
  Начальное значение: <input name="min" type="text" value="1" size="3"><br>
  Конечное значение: <input name="max" type="text" value="30" size="3">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Получить значение" 
      onclick="this.form.num.value=randomNumber(this.form.min.value,this.form.max.value)">
  <input name="num" type="text" id="num" readonly="1">
</form>
```